# Make Gmail show the subject textbox by default

Tags: gmail

How can I make Gmail show the subject line as an editable textbox by default when I reply to an email? It is hidden by default until one clicks on "Edit Subject"—I would like it to be available by default at all times. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this [Greasemonkey script](http://cache.lifehacker.com/assets/resources/lhcode/showeditablesubject.0.1.user.js) from [lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5060791/always-show-the-subject-line-when-composing-a-gmail-reply)

Copying it here for the record:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name            Show Editable Subject
// @description  Always show editable subject field when replying to a message in Gmail.
// @include         http://mail.google.com/*
// @include         https://mail.google.com/*
// @author          Gina Trapani
// @namespace   http://lifehacker.com
// @version         0.1

// @tab Compose
// @homepage http://lifehacker.com/
// ==/UserScript==


// Version 0.1: Released

// Borrowed some keyhandler code from http://bitterpill.org/gmail_tinyurl/
// Repurposed some code from http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/20887
// Based on  mathmike's the Show Details  user script http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/13700
// mathmike: Most of the functions below were borrowed from Gmail Macros (New)


var CLICK_TO_SHOW = "MRoIub";
var INNER_HTML = "Edit Subject"
var KEYCOMBO_ONLY=false;
var THIRD_KEYCODE=66; 

var gmail = null;

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  if (unsafeWindow.gmonkey) {
    unsafeWindow.gmonkey.load('1.0', function(g) {
      gmail = g;

    if (KEYCOMBO_ONLY) {
        getDoc().defaultView.addEventListener('keydown', keyHandler, false);
    } else {
        gmail.registerViewChangeCallback(handleView);
        handleView();
    }
    });
  }
}, true);

function getDoc() {
 return gmail.getNavPaneElement().ownerDocument;
}

function keyHandler(event) {
    GM_log(event.ctrlKey + ' ' + event.shiftKey + ' ' + event.keyCode);
    if (event.ctrlKey == true && event.shiftKey == true && event.keyCode == THIRD_KEYCODE) { 
         clickSpan();
    }
}

function handleView() {
     //if (gmail.getActiveViewType() == "co") clickSpan();  //Compose view
      if (gmail.getActiveViewType()=="cv") tryToClickSpan();  //Conversation view, user may hit Reply link
}

function clickSpan() {
  var nodes = 
    getNodesByTagNameAndClass(gmail.getActiveViewElement(), "span", CLICK_TO_SHOW);
  if (!nodes) return false;
  for (var i in nodes) {
      GM_log("Node " + i + " HTML is " + nodes[i].innerHTML );
      if (nodes[i].innerHTML == INNER_HTML){
        simulateClick(nodes[i], "click");
        return true;
      }
    }
}

function simulateClick(node, eventType) {
  var event = node.ownerDocument.createEvent("MouseEvents");
  event.initMouseEvent(eventType,
                       true, // can bubble
                       true, // cancellable
                       node.ownerDocument.defaultView,
                       1, // clicks
                       50, 50, // screen coordinates
                       50, 50, // client coordinates
                       false, false, false, false, // control/alt/shift/meta
                       0, // button,
                       node);

  node.dispatchEvent(event);
}

function getNodesByTagNameAndClass(rootNode, tagName, className) {
  var expression = 
      ".//" + tagName + 
      "[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' " + className + " ')]";

  return evalXPath(expression, rootNode);
}

function evalXPath(expression, rootNode) {
  try {
    var xpathIterator = rootNode.ownerDocument.evaluate(
      expression,
      rootNode,
      null, // no namespace resolver
      XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE,
      null); // no existing results
  } catch (err) {
    GM_log("Error when evaluating XPath expression '" + expression + "'" +
           ": " + err);
    return null;
  }
  var results = [];

  // Convert result to JS array
  for (var xpathNode = xpathIterator.iterateNext();
       xpathNode;
       xpathNode = xpathIterator.iterateNext()) {
    results.push(xpathNode);
  }

  return results;
}

function tryToClickSpan()  {
        if (!clickSpan() ) {
            setTimeout(tryToClickSpan, 500);
        }
}
```

Comment: Where do I add this code? Thank you

Comment: @Ken: you need to install the Greasemonkey extension and then add the script following [this tutorial on Instructables](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Install-Scripts-for-Greasemonkey/)

Comment: The Greasemonkey 10 API is outdated and no longer considered safe by Chrome.  Any alternative scripts?